# No acceleration for OpenGL and ImportError for modules that exist

Tags: wxpython, pyopengl

I'm writing a program using wxPython and OpenGL. The program works, but without any antialiasing, and I get these error messages: (I'm using ArchLinux)

```
INFO:OpenGL.acceleratesupport:No OpenGL_accelerate module loaded: No module named OpenGL_accelerate
```

However, when I look into my site-packages folder, I see the module present there. I have a wxPython demo program that uses GLCanvas, and it works fine, without any errors.

My program is quite similar to the GLCanvas demo, involving just translations, rotations, drawing quads and some basic lighting.

What am I doing wrong here? (The code is over 200 lines, if necessary I'll edit this and put it here)

Comment: I was also getting errors regarding numpy and numeric modules. My distro provides python-numeric and python-numpy packages. Installing these solved the problem. However, why the demo GLCanvas program worked fine without these packages remains a mystery to me.